# webserver goahead header question

Tags: webserver

I'm writing a small web API routine using webserver Goahead.
What's the API to be used to get the Http header information.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific to your question. I am using GoAhead for my Embedded Web Server.

You need to define the form like below to handle the subit methods (Get/POST)

```
void formSetLoopCode (webs_t wp, char_t *path, char_t *query)
{   
    a_assert (wp);
    int opt,port;
    opt  = gatoi (websGetVar (wp, "opt", "1"));
    port  = gatoi (websGetVar (wp, "port", "1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The header information is converted into variables that are retrieved using websGetVar.

Comment: I've removed the unrelated product link from your answer; it has nothing to do with what the OP was asking.

Comment: The product link is to direct people to where the product now is. GoAhead has been acquired and users can't find the new 3.X version.  I've improved the answer too.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to be a place for you to announce that people need to update their bookmarks. The user was not asking "where can I find..." In fact, it's difficult to figure out what the user is asking at all. At any rate; anyone who cares can see the URL in your profile, and this comment can serve to let them know that's where they can find the URL.